# How to request subsequent NGRX state data in the right way?

Tags: angular, redux, state, ngrx

My REST-API returns data in very normalized way:

```js
// http://localhost:8080/api/shoppingcartpositions
export interface ShoppingCartPosition {
  id: number;
  articleId: number;
  supplierId: number;
  manufacturerId: number;
  quantity: number;
}

// http://localhost:8080/api/articles?id=0&id=1&id=2...
export interface Article {
  id: number;
  description: string;
  price: number;
}

// http://localhost:8080/api/suppliers?id=0&id=1&id=2...
export interface Supplier {
  id: number;
  addressId: number;
  name: string;
}

// ... And so on
```

I have a appropriate slice of state for each of that entities:

```js
export interface ShoppingCartState extends EntityState<ShoppingCartPosition> { }
export interface ArticleState extends EntityState<Article> { }
export interface SupplierState extends EntityState<Supplier> { }
```

The state is split on resource level, because in other parts of my application I need to work with suppliers/articles (out of cart context) again. So if they are already loaded - it's fine.

**Problem:**

When my `ShoppingCartComponent` is initialized, an action is dispatched:

```js
this.store.dispatch(ShoppingCartActions.loadInitial());
```

This will request all `ShoppingCartPosition` entities from my API. This is handled inside my `ShoppingCartEffects` class

*shopping-cart.effects.ts*

```js
readonly load$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ShoppingCartActions.loadInitial),
    exhaustMap(() => this.shoppingCartService.loadPositions().pipe(
      map(positions => ShoppingCartActions.loadInitialComplete({ positions });
    )
  );
});
```

**As soon the `ShoppingCartPositions` arrive, I want to load the related data (`Suppliers` and `Articles`)!**

I also use an effect for that:

*shopping-cart.effects.ts*

```js
readonly requestRelatedData$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ShoppingCartActions.loadInitialComplete),
    switchMap((positions) => [
      SupplierActions.fetch({ ids: positions.map(x => x.SupplierId) }),
      ArticleActions.fetch({ ids: positions.map(x => x.ArticleId) })
    ])
  );
});
```

*Of course only missing entities are loaded (not yet in store). This logic is left out for code brevity...*

These dispatched actions are handled in the responsible `Effect` classes and will be updated in the matching `Reducers`.

Now when I want to use my data, I came along with a selector:

*shopping-cart.selectors.ts*

```js
export class ShoppingCartSelectors {
  private static supplierState = (state: AppState) => state.suppliers;
  private static articleState = (state: AppState) => state.articles;
  private static shoppingCartState = (state: AppState) => state.cartPositions;

  static positions = createSelector(
    this.supplierState,
    this.articleState,
    this.shoppingCartState,
    (suppliers, articles, positions) => {
      return positions.map(pos => ({
        ...pos,
        article: articles.find(...),
        supplier: suppliers.find(...)
      });
    }
  )
}
```

**This approach is working very well. But I have big problems to recognize when all data is arrived / loaded.
How can I make sure that all data-relations has been loaded?**

A possible way would be:

```js
this.store.select(ShoppingCartSelectors.positions).pipe(
  filter(pos => !!pos.article && !!pos.supplier)
)
```

But this way seems not very clean to me. And if `null` / `undefined` were valid values ( because an `Article` was removed) this would not work anymore.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You could forkJoin the retrieval of your related data, then pass the resulting values where they need to go. ForkJoin will only emit the values once all of its observables have emitted a value. Someone please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Brandon So should I `forkJoin` all my requests inside the `ShoppingCartEffect` - then invoke the completed `Actions` of Supplier/Article entities? Is that really in line with the framework? Does this work not belongs to the right entity `Reducers`?

Comment: I typically don't make fetch or http calls in an effect. I make those in a service class and return the Observable back in the effect.

Comment: I would forkJoin the requests, then pass the resulting values to your actions. The reducers will receive data from the actions. A reducer doesn't have the ability, nor should it, to know it needs to wait for one or more HTTP calls to complete, imo.

Comment: That's correct. But the correct state slices have to be updated, when the data was retrived inside the service. To do this, I have to dispatch an action, which is caught up by the reducer. But this actions are a little "out of scope" of the ShoppingCartEffect

Comment: You can dispatch more than one action in an effect

Comment: Okay- then it's fine to skip the "Initial Load Actions" and just invoke the "Completed Actions"?

Comment: Possibly. I would need to know a lot more about how your application works :)

Comment: why not add one or more flags to indicate if loading is pending or done for example. This permits also to display a loader indicator? You just have to add it in state, and set it in reducer. But maybe I misunderstood your real problem.